# Disable session timer update per action in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: session, asp.net-core-mvc, action

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application that uses session state management through `services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache`.

On a page that uses a lot of web services tied to controls, this causes the database to be hit multiple times per page load just to update the session timer. Is there a way to indicate that a specific action should NOT update the session timer?

I still want access to the session data, I just don't want to update the session timer for specific actions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no such configuration, we may need to write middleware to achieve this function.

First of all, we need to understand what a session is, its role is to maintain the session connection between the server and the client. Every time our browser sends a request to the server, a new session id is generated, and the session expiration time is also understood to be re-timed.

---

General login information will be stored in the cookie, we can find `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` or `ASP.NET_SessionId`, this information will not change until it expires.

Assuming a simple scenario, userid and time are stored after logging in. At this time, we don't need to care about each session id. Every time we make a request, we will get the last login time of useid. After comparison, we can judge whether we need to close this session.

When you want clear the current seesion, you can logout the user and clear the cookie.

```
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete(".AspNetCore.Identity.Application");
```